# how to find minimum value of each column in a 10x10 matrix vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

I need some help in finding the minimum value in each column of my 10x10 matrix.
My matrix is not displayed in the spreadsheet so I cant use worksheetfunction.min(cells(1,j),cells(10,j)) for example.

Also, i want to replace the cell next to the cell which contains the minimum value as blank.

thank you for your help

Cheers

`for j=1 to n
worst=application.worksheetfunction.min(c(1,j),c(2,j),c(3,j),c(4,j),c(5,j),c(6,j),c(7,j),c(8,j),c(9,j),c(10,j))
next j`

this code works well but it causes problem if i want to change the dimension of my matrix.

Comment: To get better help, you should explain [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and where you are stuck, for example by showing the code that does not work as expected.

Comment: `My matrix is not displayed in the spreadsheet` -- what does that mean? The `Cells` property can access every cell on every worksheet, even if the cell is hidden. `i want to replace the cell next to the cell which contains the minimum value as blank.` We need to see sample input and expected output.

Comment: Did you try just using `Application.Min(c)` - did that not work?

Answer (score 1):

`UBound(c, 2)` will give you the number of columns in the array.

So your code would look something like this (building from [Doc Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11807177/190829)'s answer):

```
For j = LBound(c, 2) To UBound(c, 2) ' columns
  worst = c(1, j)
  For i = LBound(c) To UBound(c) ' rows
    If c(i, j) < worst Then
      worst = c(i, j)
    End If
  Next i
  ' do something with 'worst' here
Next j
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample VBA code (untested, just out of my head):

```
for j=1 to n
 worst=c(1,j) 
 for i = 2 to 10  ' replace 10 by any other value you like
     if c(i,j)< worst then worst=c(i,j)
 next i
next j
```

Comment: is there any way to do it without loop? thanks for the reply :)

Comment: @user1525225: In pure VBA? I don't think so. Why?

Comment: because when i compare this code with worksheetfunction.min, it takes longer using the loop to run my simulation..

Comment: @user1525225: Did you measure it or is this just wild guessing? Your original code has to inspect all ten values of the column, just as mine. I don't expect any significant performance differences.

Comment: i measure it using the timer. maybe because i run it for 10,000 simulation, so it is slower around 1 sec

Comment: @user1525225: and does it matter? One could try to optimize this, but I guess the code would become less easy to read/understand.

Comment: yeah, i am trying to minimise the duration of my simulations, since it is one of the criteria of the assignment..thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

**First answer**

This was my first answer.  I had not read your question carefully and had not noticed you wanted minimum per column.  I have left this answer because it might still be of value.

Some worksheet functions work on arrays.  Try the following code.

Originally the minimum value in Test2 was 1 and the routine found that value in two different locations.  I deleted 1 from the array and added 51 at the end.  The routine then found 2.

I have not timed this routine but I would be amazed if it was not faster than VBA.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Try()

  Dim InxT11 As Long
  Dim InxT12 As Long
  Dim InxT2 As Long

  Dim Test1(1 To 10, 1 To 5) As Long
  Dim Test2() As Variant

  Test2 = Array(5, 20, 27, 30, 45, 50, 4, 15, 32, 33, 47, 49, 3, 11, 12, _
                21, 34, 40, 2, 10, 13, 18, 19, 24, 25, 26, 36, 42, 43, 44, _
                6, 7, 17, 31, 39, 41, 8, 9, 14, 16, 22, 23, 28, 29, 35, 37, _
                38, 46, 48, 51)

  InxT2 = LBound(Test2)
  For InxT11 = LBound(Test1, 1) To UBound(Test1, 1)
    For InxT12 = LBound(Test1, 2) To UBound(Test1, 2)
      Test1(InxT11, InxT12) = Test2(InxT2)
      InxT2 = InxT2 + 1
    Next
  Next

  Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Min(Test1)

End Sub
```

**Second answer**

For this answer I have used a ragged or jagged array.  With a ragged array each row can have a different number of columns.  All my rows are the same length but they could have been different lengths with no significant change to the code.

I have defined `Test` as a fixed size variant array.  It could just as easily have been dynamic.

A variant, or an element of a variant array, can be an array.  I have set each element of `Test` to a five element array.

The loop displays the minimum of each row as a string: 5 4 3 2 13 26 6 8 22 37.

You asked for the minimum of each column but I cannot think of an approach (other than a VBA loop) that would achieve that.  If you liked this approach you would have to make columns the first dimension and rows the second dimension.

Note: the syntax for accessing the element of a ragged array is different.  It is:

```
Debug.Print Test(InxD1)(InxD2)
```

Hope this helps.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Try2()

  Dim InxT As Long

  Dim Test(1 To 10) As Variant

  Test(1) = Array(5, 20, 27, 30, 45)
  Test(2) = Array(50, 4, 15, 32, 33)
  Test(3) = Array(47, 49, 3, 11, 12)
  Test(4) = Array(21, 34, 40, 2, 10)
  Test(5) = Array(13, 18, 19, 24, 25)
  Test(6) = Array(26, 36, 42, 43, 44)
  Test(7) = Array(6, 7, 17, 31, 39)
  Test(8) = Array(41, 8, 9, 14, 16)
  Test(9) = Array(22, 23, 28, 29, 35)
  Test(10) = Array(37, 38, 46, 48, 51)

  For InxT = LBound(Test) To UBound(Test)
    Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Min(Test(InxT)) & " ";
  Next
  Debug.Print

  Debug.Print Test(1)(2)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some actual timings, just so you can see why "avoiding loops" isn't always the win you're looking for:

```
Sub Tester()
    Const NUM_REPS As Long = 10000
    Dim arr(1 To 10, 1 To 10)
    Dim r As Integer, c As Integer, t, l As Long, v, worst

    For r = 1 To 10
        For c = 1 To 10
            arr(r, c) = Rnd() * 10
        Next c
    Next r

    'worst (~5-6 sec)
    t = Timer
    For l = 1 To NUM_REPS
        worst = arr(1, 1)
        For c = 1 To 10
            v = Application.Min(Application.Index(arr, 0, c))
            If v < worst Then worst = v
        Next c
    Next l
    Debug.Print worst, Timer - t

    'better (0.4sec)
    t = Timer
    For l = 1 To NUM_REPS
        worst = Application.Min(arr)
    Next l
    Debug.Print worst, Timer - t

    '###best### (~0.05 sec)
    t = Timer
    worst = arr(1, 1)
    For l = 1 To NUM_REPS
        For r = 1 To 10
            For c = 1 To 10
                v = arr(r, c)
                If v < worst Then worst = v
            Next c
        Next r
    Next l
    Debug.Print worst, Timer - t

End Sub
```